# How can I export/import keyboard shortcuts for spyder IDE

Tags: ide, spyder

I am new to Spyder. I have configured my preferred keyboard shortcuts on the Spyder on my home computer. Now I would like to use the same shortcuts on my working computer.

I followed the advice here (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spyderlib/0A6v9Ekrup8) to export the settings. However, although some settings (like display) are exported when I copy and overwrite the spyder.ini file, the shortcuts are not.

Can someone advise how I can export and import the keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) We're sorry but Spyder doesn't have the ability to export/import shortcuts right now (May 2019).

Several users have asked for this functionality, so we'll try to add it in a future release.